# MessageParser.ParseFrom - GUID issue

Tags: protobuf-net, protocol-buffers

I have generated proto file "Tutotial.Person" which contains a field called ID type GUID. 
I have a DTO called Person class in the C# project and I want to populate Tutorial.Person class from person object. Everything looks good but GUID. After parsing the Guid value looks like this "\t{}]2�p�D\u0011�O[X�]o". 
I am pretty new to this proto thing (as you may notice from my naive example below). Could you tell me what I would need to do to get right GUID?

```
      static void Main(string[] args) {
            var person = new Person {
                Name = "Fred",
                Id = Guid.NewGuid()
            };

            var parser = new MessageParser<Tutorial.Person>(() => new Tutorial.Person());
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Serializer.Serialize(stream, person);

                var d = parser.ParseFrom(stream.ToArray());
            }  
        }
```

Proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package tutorial;


message Person {
  string name = 1;
  string id = 2;
}
```

Comment: Small note: "After parsing the Guid value looks like this ..." - protobuf isn't a text format; it is meaningless to show a text dump. If you want to show payloads, use hex, base-64, or similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protobuf doesn't have a well-known type for storing guids. Protobuf-net made up a layout, but it isn't a flat string. It is more complex than that, but the details aren't useful.

Short version: if you want to round-trip between platforms / libraries: stick to types that have native protobuf representations. In this case, `string` would be a fair choice, rather than `Guid`.